# Is it possible to create a JPG from a Control?

Tags: c#, custom-controls, jpeg

Lets say I have a custom control (child of System.Windows.Forms.UserControl) such as a graph. Is there a way I can take the drawing I did on the control and just export the current graphical state of the control to a JPG file?

Comment: witch kind of control are you using?

Comment: @gjsduarte Edited my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. Basically you will need to ask the control to render itself to a Bitmap and then save the Bitmap as jpeg

See the documentation of [Control.DrawToBitmap()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) method.

```
Bitmap bmp = [Control.DrawToBitmap();
            bmp.Save("", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Yep, that a better one. You may also use the ClientRectangle.Width, and ClientRectangle.Height for the size parameters.

Comment: Looks to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!